# How to install cryptography for python3 in Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, pip

When executing `pip3 install cryptography`, `pip3` gives an error:

> fatal error: 'openssl/aes.h' file not found
>   `#include <openssl/aes.h>`
>
> 1 error generated.
>   error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

I checked with `brew info openssl` and got the answer:

> Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
>   own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
>   build variables:
>
> `LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`
>      `CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include`

The problem now is: how can I tell `pip` add the paths into corresponding build variables when it uses `clang` to compile cpp file?

Comment: related: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2350

Comment: @user2393267, cryptography is a very generic tag, it makes little sense to add it here.

Answer (score 11):

Trying to install the scrapy I need to install cryptography package on Mac OS El Capitan. As explained in Cryptography installation doc

`env LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" pip install cryptography`