# pip install produces the following error on mac: error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, pip

So I tried to install a package from PyPI with the following command:

```
sudo pip3 install switcheo
```

But it fails to install the package in the end.

```
Error checking for conflicts.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2584, in version
return self._version
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2691, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _version

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 503, in _warn_about_conflicts
package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py", line 108, in check_install_conflicts
package_set, _ = create_package_set_from_installed()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py", line 47, in create_package_set_from_installed
package_set[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2589, in version
raise ValueError(tmpl % self.PKG_INFO, self)
ValueError: ("Missing 'Version:' header and/or METADATA file", Unknown [unknown version] (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages))
Installing collected packages: scrypt, neocore, switcheo

scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto/crypto_aes.c:6:10: fatal error: 'openssl/aes.h' file not found
#include <openssl/aes.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-b6w97vc0/scrypt/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-qvammwag/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-b6w97vc0/scrypt/
```

This is the full output in the terminal after running the pip install line.
I found some solutions for linux, but there are not a lot of posts here for mac users.

Comment: Please always post _the full error message_.

Comment: Have you tried installing inside a virtual environment?

Comment: Okay I updated the post with the rest of the error messages, But I left out the rest of the terminal output because it was too much.

Comment: Basically, the file `openssl/aes.h` isn't present in your system, which means you should install a library called OpenSSL

Comment: The error is `fatal error: 'openssl/aes.h' file not found`. Similar to [openssl-aes-h-file-not-found-on-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693149/openssl-aes-h-file-not-found-on-mac).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I dealt with this problem for a while while trying to install another library that relies on openssl in a MacOS virtual env.

Mac has deprecated openssl in favor of their own SSL. So what you need to do is:

```
    brew install openssl
```

or if it is already installed,

```
    brew reinstall openssl
```

Now you need to to change the LD and CPP Flags. Refer to the openssl reinstall dialog. Should tell you where the commands!

openssl is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries.

If you need to have openssl first in your PATH run:

```
    echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

For compilers to find openssl you may need to set:

```
    export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
    export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

For pkg-config to find openssl you may need to set:

```
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for the reply, I had made a separate post with a similar question and still no concrete solution. This seems to do the trick.

Comment: Great! Took me a while to figure this out as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're either missing the OpenSSL package, or your system can't find where it is on your system. Try `brew install openssl`.

A more detailed answer [openssl/aes.h' file not found on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693149/openssl-aes-h-file-not-found-on-mac/45750293#45750293)

Answer (score 0):

after spending hours, i successfullly installed.

- If you are using mac and if you are using anaconda
- please open python terminal from anaconda
- then paste the following link and click enter.
- conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 wordcloud
- if you need more clarity please visit following link
  https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/wordcloud